# SSIS adding new columns to the Source

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS. I have a problem.  i get data from two different data sources. I am able to merge them using Merge Component and feed the output to a Script component where i validate data and move it to the destination. Every thing is working fine. I want it to work when we add some extra columns in any sources.

The problem is when i add extra columns in source, i should add the input columns in the script component(check the ckeck boxes in Input Columns).  Is there any way to do this?

Plz help

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the new column to the source, open the package and then follow the flow through.  You will have to go into subsequent controls including the merge control to refresh the data with this new field.

SSIS will prompt you with the exclamation mark at each stage where a refresh is mandatory(such as source control), although you will have to manually step through the flow components (such as merge) where a column output is optional.

For example, I added cost as a new column to the basic ole db source below
[image: data flow example]

and after updating the source control, I have the opportunity to add it to the script component as you mention - but it is not mandatory for me to do so

[image: script option]

the new field should be available in the sort component, even if its not used within the script control.  You will however need to tick the field as a pass through on the sort control to get it into the merge component

[image: sort control fields]

Comment: Thanks for the response Daryl.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daryl. The problem is when i add a new column in the Source i am gettin it as output from the source. When i feed the output as an input to the Script Component, the newly added column checkbox is not checked in the input columns of the script component.  which does not allow my newly added column to move to the destination.

Comment: You should not have to add it as an input to the script component, unless you need to manipulate it with script.  I will expand my answer with an example

Comment: Thanks Daryl. I am validating all the fields in the Script component. So whenever  a new column is added to the Scouce it should be checked as input to the Script component. Is there any way to do that? We cannot modify and deploy the Package eachtime a new column is added..

Comment: Creating a new column tends to be a relatively infrequent event.  I dont think there is a way to automate a package to automatically pick up on a new column and include it within certain components.  You could use View code to get the xml format of the package before and after you a a new column and emulate these changes (i.e. change the xml accordingly).  This could be quite a task (especially if you utilise that column within you controls / destination) and you will still have to release the new package

Comment: Thanks Daryl...Is there any work around or any other way to do this? If not can you please throw some light on how to do the XML thing. I am a newbie to SSIS.

Comment: Not that I'm aware off.  That is the purpose of the ssis interface.  Editing the XML directly is not for the  fainthearted!  you will have to compare a "before and after" view of the package to see what elements change when adding a new column to a script an emulate the steps.  It's certainly not the best way to edit a package, but you are limiting your options somewhat by not wanting to use the interface provided.  Good luck!